# Hard drive issue on Linux

Tags: linux, debian, hardware, external-hdd

I'v recently bought some old hard drives from a company that barely used them and wanted to use them to create a RAID 1 array. When I connect them to my linux desktop it doesn't reconise the drives at all and at start up I get the following errors:

[image: Errors on linux boot]

Now before you jump to the conclusion they are just dead hard drives (like me at first). The drives seem to work perfectly fine on Windows. I can partition them, add them to storage spaces, etc. The only thing I cannot do is do a SMART scan with the seagate tool but that might be because it doesn't have it (old drives). It is vital that the drives work on linux to be the start of my NAS.

Any help is appreciated!

Edit:

The answers to the quesions asked in the comments:

1. The drives do not have delayed jumper settings
2. Yes both drives (identical) have the same issue when connected individually
3. The kernel version is 6.1.0-11amd64
4. Software raid mdadm
5. USB Micro-B (3.0) connector

If it helps the drives are both Lacie Rugged USB3.0 FW 800.

Update:

I also got the following error at start up (not shown on screenshot)

> ima: Error Communicating to TPM (x6)

Comment: Do the drives have jumper settings for delayed or staggered spin-up?

Comment: Interesting issue! Assuming they are **perfectly** working under Win, I have two questions: **first**, do they show the same issue when connected individually? **second**, what kernel version are you using?

Comment: 1- The drives do not have delayed jumper settings
2- Yes both drives (identical) have the same issue when connected individually
3- The kernel version is 6.1.0-11amd64

Comment: I miss a piece: how do you create a RAID with **external** drives?

Comment: Software raid, planning to use mdadm, if I can get the drives to work

Comment: How do you connect them to the PC?

Comment: USB Micro-B (3.0)

Comment: Please [edit] your Question to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by both current and future readers (who have better answers).  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.

Comment: Divide yout ptoblem onto smaller chunks. Test one drive at a time, and try to get it to be a disk. Use `gparted`, ensure you've selected the correct disk for `gparted`. Do you have any documentation on the disks? C/H/S? "Works on Windows"? What are the "properties" on Windows? I think it's available from RightMouseHold menu. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

Comment: You are dropping into emergency mode because your system cannot mount the EFI System Partition at `/boot/efi`. If you have not yet set up the new (old) disks, this error should be completely unrelated to the new disks. That said, a "Lacie Rugged USB3.0 FW 800" should have a disk that are not older than the USB 3.0 specification, so the inability to do a SMART scan would be suspicious. Did you confirm the disks can actually store non-trivial amounts of data in Windows? These might be counterfeits with a firmware that makes them *appear* to work just enough to fool Windows.